# What would be a use case for Thread.Sleep(Timeout.Infinite)?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I happened to lay my eyes on an intellisense tool tip regarding the parameter passed to `System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(int millisecondsTimeout)`, saying something like "(…) *Specify System.Threading.Timeout.Infinite to block the thread indefinitely*". And I am intrigued.

I can understand why one might include short inactive delays within a possibly endless loop, thus yielding processing power to other executing threads when no immediate action in the sleeping thread is required, although I typically prefer implementing such delays with `EventWaitHandler`s so that I can avoid waiting a full sleeping delay if I signal the thread to gracefully end its execution from a different thread.

But I cannot see when I might need to suspend a thread indefinitely, and in a way that, as far as I can tell, can only be interrupted through a rather ungraceful `Thread.Abort()`/`ThreadAbortException` pair.

So what would be a working scenario where I might want to suspend a thread indefinitely?

Comment: Maybe in a workflow related task? There may be a job you have to do once a year (or at an ad-hoc basis) and you will expect a task (part of the workflow) to appear on that anniversary, so you would put it to sleep until that time.  Not an ideal scenario, but just trying to see where you would need a delay that long.

Answer (score 12):

It is a pretty long story and I have to wave my hands a bit to make it understandable.  Most programmers think that Thread.Sleep() puts the thread to sleep and prevents it from executing any code.  This is not accurate.  Thread.Sleep(Infinite) is equivalent to Application.Run().  No kidding.

This doesn't happen very often in real life, it is mostly relevant in custom hosting scenarios.  Getting code to run on a specific thread is in general an important feature to deal with code that is not thread-safe and the major reason why Application.Run() exists.  But Windows exposes another way to do at a much lower level, the underlying api for this is [QueueUserAPC()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684954(v=vs.85).aspx).  The .NET analogue of this function is BeginInvoke().

This requires the thread to co-operate, just like it does when it calls Application.Run().  The thread must be in an "alertable wait state", executing a blocking function that can be interrupted.  The CLR does not execute the sleep by itself, it passes the job to the [CLR host](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/unmanaged-api/hosting/ihosttaskmanager-sleep-method).  Most hosts will simply execute [SleepEx()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686307(v=vs.85).aspx), passing TRUE for the bAlertable argument.  The thread is now in a state to execute any requests posted by QueueUserAPC().  Just like it will be when it is actively executing inside the Application.Run() dispatcher loop.

The kernel feature is not otherwise exposed at all in the framework.  It is the kind of code that is very hard to get right, re-entrancy bugs are pretty nasty.  As most programmers that were bitten by Application.DoEvents() or a poorly placed MessageBox.Show() can attest.  It is however a valid scenario in a custom hosting scenario.  Where the host can get C# code to run on a specific thread, using this mechanism.  So it is possible to pass Infinite because the designers did not want to intentionally disable this scenario.  If this is made possible at all by the host author then they'd let you know about it.  I don't know of a practical example.

More practically, you do use this feature every day.  It is the way that System.Threading.Timer and System.Timers.Timer are implemented.  Done by a thread inside the CLR which is started as soon as you use any timer, it uses [SleepEx(INFINITE, TRUE)](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/src/vm/win32threadpool.cpp#L2633) at its core.

Comment: Thank you Hans for your response. It does not quite address my question (unless you are suggesting that one use case I may find is if I decide to implement my own Timer class) but it is nevertheless interesting; I wish you could have gone for the longer answer. I am further intrigued by part of your reply, however. You mention that Thread.Sleep(Infinite) is equivalent to Application.Run() and I think I can see that in the sense that both are blocking calls that are not quite as blocking as one would think. (Continued)

Comment: (Continuation) However, while Application.Run() enters a Windows message loop, allowing me to execute code in the same thread without ending the call to Application.Run(), as far as I can understand it, Thread.Sleep(Infinite) will not let me execute callback functions in the same thread before exiting the call to Thread.Sleep, or will it? Thanks again!

Comment: I wrote the answer entirely focused on the feature that it *does* permit executing callback functions on the same thread.  I wish I could give you a better example of it, custom hosts are however never well documented.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `.Interrupt()` to *wake* a sleeping thread (causing `ThreadInterruptedException` in the code that was calling `.Sleep()`, which can be caught and handled), so this provides *a* mechanism to say "sleep until someone prods you". I'm not saying it is necessarily the *best* mechanism for this, but: it may have uses for you.

Comment: Thanks Marc, I had not realised there was an Interrupt function. Would placing the call to Thread.Sleep(Infinite) inside a Try/Catch block handling ThreadInterruptExceptions, and calling .Interrupt() from a different thread, be functionally equivalent to calling WaitOne(Infinite) on the sleeping thread and signalling the event from a different thread? The latter seems cleaner.